# Kotlin Android Extensions and Menu

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

Is there any way to access **menu_item_search** menu item defined in **fragment_photo_gallery** layout using synthetic properties instead of using **findItem** method?

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater)
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_photo_gallery, menu)

    //is there a way to access searchItem using synthetic properties?
    val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search)
}
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [Kotlin Android Extensions - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)? I'm not using Kotlin for Android currently but from what I can tell you simply need to add an import like `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<layout>.*` and then you should be able to use a synthetic property named `menu_item_search` in your activity code.

Comment: Yes I have indeed. Your 'solution' works only for layout inflated in onCreate method (you can access every layou item reffering it's name). Menu layout is inflated in onCreateOptionsMenu and I was not able to access menu_item_search using it's name (synthetic variable).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MenuInflater` serves a fundamentally different purpose than `LayoutInflater`.

Despite both having "Inflater" part in its name and implementing methods that are named "inflate()", they do completely different things. `MenuInflater` inflates `Menu`s, where `LayoutInflater` inflates `View`s.

[Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) were created to simplify usage of Android Views, not Android Menus, or anything that has `inflate()` method.

Long story short - it is not possible to use KAE with Android Menus.

Comment: That's great explanation